# Как скруглить углы внутрь блока с обводкой

Tags: css

Интересует верстка блока с закругленными внутрь углами. Важно не просто их скруглить, но и сохранить обводку у блока. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно еще посмотреть в сторону jquery решения если не хочется возиться с css http://malsup.com/jquery/corner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Версия @Ruslan_K, но с границами:

```css
#main {
    margin: 40px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main .edge {
    position: absolute;
}

#main .edge.top {
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#main .edge.left {
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#main .corner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#main .corner.top { top: -10px; }
#main .corner.bottom { bottom: -10px; }
#main .corner.left { left: -10px; }
#main .corner.right { right: -10px; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="edge top"></div>
    <div class="edge left"></div>
    <div class="corner top left"></div>
    <div class="corner top right"></div>
    <div class="corner bottom left"></div>
    <div class="corner bottom right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Основная идея: вырезать лишние области с помощью псевдоэлементов.
Понадобится всего два блока в разметке (`.wrapper` и `.content`):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #efefef;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 40px;
  /**
   * Ключевые свойства
   * С помощью position: relative будем позиционировать псевдоэлементы для вырезания границ
   * С помощью overflow: hidden будем делать сектора
   */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Для наглядной демонстрации работы, не нужно в проекте */
.wrapper.demo {
  border: 2px solid #bad;
  overflow: visible;
}

.content {
  /* Цвет границы блока должен совпадать с границей будущих вырезанных секторов */
  border: 2px solid #07c;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper::before,
.wrapper::after,
.content::before,
.content::after {
  /* Цвет следует подобрать в цвет фона сайта для перекрытия части основного блока */
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Цвет границы блока должен совпадать с границей основного блока */
  border: 2px solid #07c;
  /* Делаем окружность */
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  /* Позиционируется относительно .wrapper. Это важно для понимания. */
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

/* Позиционирование будущих секторов: верхний ряд */
.wrapper::before,
.wrapper::after {
  top: -15px;
}

.wrapper::before {
  left: -15px;
}

.wrapper::after {
  right: -15px;
}

/* Позиционирование будущих секторов: нижний ряд */
.content::before,
.content::after {
  bottom: -15px;
}

.content::before {
  left: -15px;
}

.content::after {
  right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper demo">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Блок с классом `.demo` добавлен только для понимания того, как это все работает.

---

Если необходимо сделать поддержку двойного фона у сектора, этого можно добиться, залив псевдоэлементы [линейным градиентом](https://webref.ru/layout/html5-css3/background/linear-gradient).

Сгенерировать градиент можно с помощью online-сервиса [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Answer (score 3):

```css
#main {
    margin: 40px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.top { top: -10px; }
.bottom { bottom: -10px; }
.left { left: -10px; }
.right { right: -10px; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="top left"></div>
    <div class="top right"></div>
    <div class="bottom left"></div>
    <div class="bottom right"></div>
</div>
```