# Как средствами css можно сделать таким образом скругленный внутрь угол? Спасибо

Tags: css

Обычное скругление внутрь я знаю как сделать (например, с помощью псевдоэлементов), но не понимаю, как можно сделать скругление такой волной, как здесь:

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать скругленный переход между двумя блоками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1312065/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="440.000000pt" height="315.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 440.000000 315.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<g transform="translate(0.000000,315.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="orange" stroke="none">
<path d="M1055 3100 c-827 -6 -781 -2 -858 -69 -19 -18 -46 -53 -59 -79 l-23
-47 -3 -1295 c-2 -959 0 -1305 9 -1335 18 -63 62 -118 121 -150 l53 -30 1550
0 1550 0 53 30 c56 30 100 83 120 144 7 19 12 77 12 131 0 198 70 319 228 393
58 27 78 31 196 37 147 7 189 21 243 83 67 76 64 22 61 1067 l-3 945 -22 41
c-27 51 -89 105 -140 125 -32 11 -227 14 -1188 14 -632 0 -1487 -2 -1900 -5z"/>
<path d="M3880 724 c-178 -65 -267 -268 -192 -437 29 -64 95 -132 161 -164 47
-23 69 -28 136 -28 67 0 89 5 136 28 66 32 132 99 162 165 33 71 31 188 -5
264 -31 67 -91 127 -156 159 -62 29 -179 36 -242 13z m134 -277 c22 -12 41
-27 43 -34 5 -13 -68 -63 -92 -63 -12 0 -15 13 -15 60 0 68 5 71 64 37z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Такой блок Вам всё же лучше сверстать при помощи svg